# IIS 10 Connection Issues when user authenticating from AT&T mobile network

Tags: asp.net, azure, iis-10

We have an asp.net webforms site we are migrating to IIS 10, server 2022 datacenter Azure Edition VM, from an IIS 8.5 Server 2012 R2 Azure VM.

When testing the site on the new platform, the issue surfaces after a user on AT&T mobile submits credentials at the log in page, is authenticated and redirected to the protected content area. At this point the site hangs, sometimes the protected content page will partially load and/or the connection times out with a reset. Other times it will not load the protected content area at all. Prior to LogIn authentication, that same User can access other non-protected content pages over https as normal.

The site performs as expected when accessing from any other network. Everything also works if a VPN is used to access the site over the same AT&T mobile data connection.

When the protected content area hangs. If we keep the browser open and enable the VPN afterwards using the same Mobile connection the content will load normally without having to reauthenticate.

There are no issues on the original server 2012 R2 running IIS 8.5 even using AT&T mobile.

Other info:

- Forms Authentication - Target framework 4.7.2
- Confirmed the user authenticates on the server with their login creds and is issued auth cookie over SSL. Auth cookie appears in the response header on client machine. AppAuth Cookie size 3.5kb
- Once the page hangs, the user can no longer access any prior page from the unprotected content area until they delete the site cookies.
- IIS logs show the Post from the log in and the 302 redirect.
- Wire Shark shows a successful handshake on TSL1.2 on the client machine. Sometimes see a RST, ACK in Wireshark after several data packets.
- HttpErr Log sometimes indicates Timer_EntityBody.
- Confirmed issue exists on multiple devices and connections using AT&T Mobile data. From both a browser and as a mobile hot spot connected to a computer.
- No additional Deny filters are configured in the Azure NSG.

Other Actions taken to troubleshoot:

- Disabled TLS 1.3 over TCP in IIS Bindings.
- Disabled HTTP/2 in IIS Bindings
- IIS Rebooted after changes
- Re-provisioned a different public IP and NSG for the VM in Azure.
- Set Timer_MinBytesPerSecond  = 0

What are we missing?
Is there a different setting in IIS 10 vs IIS 8.5 that could cause this issue on certain networks?

Comment: I think further analysis on the network packets is required, not merely TLS handshakes. But such analysis depends heavily on experience on similar cases, so your team should consider Microsoft support at this moment for assistance.

Comment: It is difficult to reproduce your problem based on your description, I suggest you open a case via: https://support.microsoft.com.